# How to find group center of pixels with a certain color in an image?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, graphics

I have a list of major colors present in an image (bitmap) on Android. I want to draw a few markers at approximate ***centers*** of places where each of these colors are in abundance.

I am trying to achieve this in a brute-force fashion, iterating through all the pixels and [finding "islands" of similar color](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5708658983829504) (colors whose RGBs are +/- 5 in Euclidean distance from the color of current pixel). Median of these points in each island should be the center of that color.
For an MxN image, worst case complexity would be (MxN)^2 with an extra MxN space for containing visited nodes.

Is there a better/standard algorithm to achieve this (preferably without using another library)?

For detecting the major colors, I am using the inbuilt Palette API on Android. But I can use K-Means or Median-Cut if that can help. So far, I can't figure out how can these methods help me preserve the position of the cluster center; at best I can maintain the first or last occurrence of a color.

Comment: I am not familiar with that API but it sounds to me like you should be looking for *"Image Segmentation"* (by colour), and *"Image Moments"*.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I dropped the Palette API note. it was not very useful for this question. I have tried K-Means clustering and Median cut approaches so far to extract the major colors in the image. But I can't find a way to get the center position of cluster.

Comment: Maybe you could post an image, unsegmented and clean, as well as another roughly marked up to show what you are aiming for.